# Exclude Strings values for Totals Calculation in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder3.0, power-bi-report-server

I have question in SSRS report builder  below is the data in column as
Site Information :
1,
2,
Not applicable.

So how to Calculate **sum** and **percentage** by excluding  Not applicable text value .

Please help me

Comment: I'd create a row group using that column and add a filter to the row group to exclude the "Not Applicable".

Comment: ok. But Not applicable is a text which is coming from an Expression ,by hiding some data it is kept as Not applicable , but still can we filter it ?

Comment: I want to Exclude that text for SUM Calculation

Comment: Then you can build the expression in a calculated field in the dataset. After that you can use the field in the column group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VAL()` Function. This simply converts a string into a value is the string contains only data that can be viewed as a number.

So your expression would just be something like

```
=SUM(VAL(Fields!myTextField.Value))
```